# Filter Angular List View based on current view of Google Maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-filters, ng-map

I am using Angular Google maps with a list of markers.  As the map zooms in I would like the list to shrink to only show the markers currently in view.

I have created a plunker with some code. Any help on how I could filter the list as the map zooms?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ngMap">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>
<script>
  angular.module('ngMap').controller('MyCtrl', function() {
    var vm=this;

    vm.positions =[
      {pos:[40.71, -74.15]},
      {pos:[40.72, -74.20]},
      {pos:[40.73, -74.18]},
      {pos:[40.77, -74.19]},
      {pos:[40.75, -74.17]},
      {pos:[40.76, -74.16]},
      {pos:[40.74, -74.20]}
    ];
    vm.showData = function() {
      alert(this.data.foo);
    }
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm">
    <ng-map zoom="11" center="[40.74, -74.18]">
      <marker ng-repeat="p in vm.positions"
        position="{{p.pos}}"
        title="pos: {{p.pos}}"></marker>
    </ng-map>
    <div>
      <div ng-repeat="p in vm.positions">{{p.pos}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/yyOuciyz5WAEG522eNrJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the documentation, there is no directive or configuration that will do this for you.

I created the following work-around that will filter the positions any time the bounds of the map change (filtering out those positions which do not fall between the bounds of the map), which I believe is what you're after.

---

**UPDATE 10/23/18**

Here is a better solution ---> https://embed.plnkr.co/pe6Hv5wHknxtwn4F5aST/

Comment: Nathan, that is fantastic! Thanks for the help!

Comment: For some reason this stopped working. The google api has changed or something and the bounds are different fields. I havent been able to get it to work. It just happened this morning.

Comment: Yes, looks like they changed the properties of the `bounds` (used to be `b` and `f`, now it's `j` and `l`). Anyway, there is a much better and more stable way to solve this problem. Check out https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngBounds, particularly `getNorthEast()` and `getSouthWest()`, both of which return a lat/lon pair (`bounds.getNorthEast()`) - you can use these 4 points to build `latBounds` and `lonBounds` and not have to worry about this happening again. Cheers!